# Accomplishment vs. Achievement (implicit superiority)

Tags: differences, nouns

I elsewhere saw the difference between the two explained thusly: accomplished denoted "completed for someone else's benefit", achieved "completed by oneself".
I consider it a one off, but can anyone confirm if there is an implicit superiority in language usage.
This would be useful in the positive sense one would say "... an accomplished career".

Answer (score 6):

I think you are right to be wondering if there is a difference, since in my experience (UK English, mostly academic) the two stem-words seem to be used interchangeably to mean much the same thing. If there is a shade of difference in meaning or usage, I guess that accomplish(ed) refers more to polish and style, and achieve(ment) more to overcoming difficulty. Otherwise they both mean to get something done - and finished.
I wonder if the poser of the question would like to say whether it is UK- or US- or other English usage that is of greatest interest?

Answer (score 3):

I would say that one would *accomplish* a task and *achieve* a goal or target. There is considerable overlap between the two.

Comment: Yes, there's "considerable overlap". But arguably in practice the *tasks* you accomplish may tend to have been set *by others*, whereas the *goals* you achieve might be more likely to have been *personal targets*. Which might explain where OP's cited source got the idea linking the two verbs themselves to either one's, own or someone else's, benefit.

Comment: Not necessarily: "I am an accomplished musician who achieved the top spot on Billboard!" I frankly don't find any implicit notion as to who set goals in thoise words. Many people happily describe their professional achievements which (unless they are also the boss) are not likely to have been self-designated goals.

Answer (score 1):

*Accomplishment* is getting things done, while *achievement* is getting things done right.

Answer (score 0):

Achievement is the road travelled to arrived at an intentional goal, benchmark, or destination.

Accomplishment is the gratitude to have travelled said road smoothly to its end, no matter how rocky the terrain.

Comment: Not bad, but it would be much better with citations of definitions (e.g. from a dictionary).

Answer (score -1):

Accomplishment is when something is completed to a wider, maybe even universal standard and for the benefit of many and maybe all.

Achievement is something that is completed to a much narrower standard, maybe even just your own, and to the benefit of a few, maybe even only oneself.

Comment: Please add supporting evidence to this answer.